# Why does burning propellants off of the stoichiometric ratio improve performance?

Tags: thermodynamics, rocket-science

According to Page 91 of *Ignition!: An Informal History of Liquid Rocket Propellants* by John D. Clark in the Chapter 7: Performance:

"If you're burning a hydrocarbon with oxygen, or if you're working with the CHON system in general, you generally get the maximum performance from a mixture ratio which gives a 1.05 to 1.20 ratio of reducing to oxidizing valences in the chamber--that is, you work a little on the rich side of stoichiometric to get some CO and H$_2$ to improve $R/C_p$."

The logic here seems to be that having more light (or perhaps simple) molecules improves the thermal efficiency $\eta$ of a rocket engine according to this equation
$$\eta=1-\left(\frac{P_e\ \mathrm{(Exhaust\ pressure)}}{P_c\ \mathrm{(Chamber\ pressure)}}\right)^\frac{R\ \mathrm{(Universal\ gas\ constant)}}{C_p\ (\mathrm{Specific\ heat\ at\ constant\ pressure})}$$ from page 85
by reducing what appears the specific heat at constant pressure $C_p$ which helps the exhaust velocity according to the equation $$v=\sqrt{\frac{2H\ (\mathrm{Heat\ released\ in\ the\ reaction})\ \eta\ (\mathrm{Thermal \ efficiency})}{M\ (\mathrm{Mass\ of\ the\ reactants})}}$$ Also from page 85.

By my understanding, burning propellants off stoichiometric ratio puts a fundamental limit on the efficiency of your engine, since the energy you get out of it, $\frac HM$, is less than the maximum. Does the reduced specific heat capacity offset this? If so, why? Does it make it so that the exhaust gases lose less energy to the work done by expansion?

EDIT: [This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22123/47480) on Space SE answers my question flawlessly.

Comment: See also: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22122/merlin-engine-stoichiometry and https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26432/pro-cons-of-burning-propellant-in-stochiometric-ratio